# Django + pipenv + Apache + mod_wsgi deployment on ubuntu not loading modules

Tags: django, ubuntu, virtualenv, mod-wsgi, pipenv

I'm trying to deploy django project on Ubuntu server using apache and mod_wsgi.

I'm using python3 and pipenv to manage venv.

Environment variable `PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=True` so that venv created by pipenv is located inside the project folder.

This is the project structure:

```
/srv/project
|
|-.venv # venv creted by pipenv
| |-bin
| |-...
|
|-Pipfile
|-Pipfile.lock
|
|-django_app
  |
  |-manage.py
  |-...
  |
  |-django_app
    |
    |-settings.py
    |-...
    |-wsgi.py
```

Apache VirtualHost configuration (`/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /srv/project/django_app/django_app>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-home=/srv/project/.venv python-path=/srv/project/django_app
    WSGIProcessGroup django_app
    WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/project/django_app/django_app/wsgi.py

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Apache works fine and responds correctly, until I add the WSGI part of the configuration. Then it stops responding (all requests are pending).

And same error message keeps repeating in apache error log (`/var/log/apache2/error.log`) - even when no requests are sent to server:

```
Current thread 0x00007f300f446bc0 (most recent call first):
[Tue Jan 29 15:43:58.899091 2019] [core:notice] [pid 16407:tid 139844391300032] AH00051: child pid 22818 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

It seems that the process is not able to load modules, probably due to improper venv configuration (not really using venv?). But nothing I tried helps.

I also added this code to wsgi.py, but it didn't help:

```
python_home = '/srv/project/.venv'

activate_this = python_home + '/bin/activate_this.py'
exec(open(activate_this).read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

Ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem resolved. I have performed a couple of steps, and I'm not sure which exactly of them was crucial:

1. I noticed that Python version in venv was different (3.7.2) from Python version installed in the system (3.6.2). So I downgraded the required version in Pipfile to 3.6.7 - now it's the same as system python version.
2. Removed .venv by deleting the folder (.venv) then running `pipenv --rm`
3. Created the venv again by running `pipenv install`. Of course, this newly created venv was with downgraded python version
4. Restarted apache... and voilà!

Also, the addition in wsgi.py is **unnecessary** and didn't help solve the problem:

```
python_home = '/srv/project/.venv'

activate_this = python_home + '/bin/activate_this.py'
exec(open(activate_this).read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

Hope this will help someone.